# simple_html_dom not working for HTTPS sites

Tags: php, wordpress, scrape

I love using simple_html_dom to scrape content of website and rss feeds but I came to a problem when I was trying the same on an HTTPS website. It seems that I can't get nothing out of it.

```
//  SCRAPER:
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// page to scrape
$base = 'https://kat.cr/applications/?rss=1';
// set up curl
$curl = curl_init();                                
// the url to request
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base );           
// return to variable
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
// don't verify peer ssl cert
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
//  // fetch remote contents, check for errors
if ( false === ( $response = curl_exec( $curl ) ) )
    $error = curl_error( $curl );
// close the resource
curl_close( $curl );

if ( !$response ){
    die("Curl Error: {$error}");
}
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);

$titre = $html->find('title', 2);

echo "Success... Title is: ".$titre."</br>";
```

I do think openssl is running on my server (i'm not not much of a system admin)

```
[root@nsxxxxx ~]# php -i|grep ssl
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/usr' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-sqlite3=shared,/usr' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--without-readline' '--with-libedit' '--with-pspell=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--with-tidy=shared,/usr' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-intl=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr'
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
openssl
```

The output of this php is :

```
Success... Title is:
```

a print_r($str); will return :

```
���ko�H���ϯ��Aj�\7Im��=�t.'= �-�2��%%�Y̏�S�ҥ�h�T�Ev��ӱd����������˅s_4mYWϞ0B�8E5�ge5�����O~���Ӧm�Wq}�W��u�4E�~��v�^M..̻��o����J���}z�WU�����������W�E9��Pd��rZ��ՕsS3;/��]޶�쯞^t�ue,����Vz��ɴ�xza��~?+�iS�t�������vw��b��x`�_��W���ys[��%���ij��%�y3'�,r����`���L����}�`O1��O���u��kY������{��|����Ϝ޴EsqS.�uY���]-_��v�h��j�^55�w1�͔�p�� l]��^3�)w%����PlS�|S��T�)z_�js��6�YS��C%�r8e���D�)D��Ӌ�����?����������K.�]߇(}��_�_V7�_����SA��T�0Ny��4R.��0�4���n�E �E�n���e>������/��ˇ8  ߅��&?>��m�jr�.o'}��ӬzfC��!@t�"� H�u!@6B��u�l3[�Q����n��]�P����~��mh�����_^���̊e]���T�L���.�:���R��e{I�wo|y��&^ؽ�������,f������rݠ^�����G��Џ�6O@?��#�~䠽[о�]��ʀ����4��i;�� �|z[Pg{�Eߐo�����ه�!�v�O��i@|�B�8�O��ٓ�^<��rm�}�\X�^��u�^��բp^��Z��ځ�΀���W����on�i���l�C'��������az��e��~Dm�+�n�jW0��7�[Y�j� O����o=ق���H��!L��2�e����T0�y���/�(�$��4<�>�Dy><�.��Dj�:5R� �(�@�C�� �!@�<2���XI����t�X�N����7�G�z�{��62"T��6_���yYߗ�s���J�P!a'��m��'��MPs�^j'pk���S,1��Ʃv�kI#�Y:N=C@�&. RAPI�  (�]��f�b4�* �&^(��&�+�����Ҿuj�n#�LPt�E�.95x�M��ѭzĨG:�ȶ�wI�Qi�p��I>�    �k#2�T^@�}��A�r�}��%�4�Tb���1{�B��y(���<��LrB����2 ��4�=$n #+&�e�|7JS�z�b�7jrٳNMD *sQ'�.��,�1��X4 T��N�]�����ƞ�<»>&�3A|Y��æ�?���];W���h���X�?�  S=���b��˸Ad{QV�/��Ֆ��\ۋo�Z�kqm��y�G��[y�7�N/{����$�r����7���~ʓHny ^d1ҥ�Hx�&����}��|;�i�Q�9�4Gy����!ǆA�@1�#�b�S�����M��a=B��v�2v����K���a�z���y��U�������Yq_t�c�3���~�W*UЛ~�T�r"�wz�C�28eJ&^�R��K����,UQ,�0��Oi�(��}����@x��N�Ǿ�Q �E#�!��h���� �1��g�m#�����]��uUv��լ�+�m^.>B6���f`��E�d�NX͚���[w�h��;x\ַe��-g���d�L�S��q���t������o��ц�[wh���y9fm���N�`���Vԣ����}   ��ċU$R/�!O�̂�r7J\_JW�j��q�:5�Q���Yj!h4$VC�iH���jH@C�����[w���{��Z���=imc����?���r���o�j]lJ���Mt�ۙ�ͷ��x��=�̓�������x�Y�)xu�nYw}�yb� )Մ�$��+78�2J��b�G�R�PI��(�i��I�8����}�Ԑ<44�##8��#��{ؖ\cpF.b�"V.͕�\c��o@�����{�٧}ԡ����u�,�p� �����p�Y�Ku|B�ؿ�Irf��Z�f}��m���Y���r�ݨ�?@��K<,~K��'����}k%/`��'�8u ��ς��,I�0�a�r��܌�q�Q��}��F���Pxd��t��.��1܍0Z�ȡjĪi�U��裌=�{t�q���k�F��OM��-�����~���'�T^t+���ze����K.i ������xn�ƺ)ݲmm���pm��!����1jF>���^����;%���'�m   $|���CJ3����)Wx���8�}��X<u�##>ډ�:��V����B�P;�iG�vd���#[�F�{��"O���sl�Ĉ�ܣ0k�b��F��9kr��w�ܸ���=�n���B�b�����̽��M79qp���%������}~�*�IQЌe��4�C%���'�W����}=�Ԁ�cL��v"?�x�;���";�F��z��������)I��*��Gǅ|�)���|꼾r~�����_��ͧ��l9)(a�l5��Th�g�b�Bg�)�̧�n��/��.��1l@�vb�C�%Nڠ=O�Еe,r]�).�������
```

Any help, even just a clue about where ot look at would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, this code is developed in a wordpress plugin in the function.php file. It might be related to the issue, looking into it.

Comment: Is `curl` returning the contents of the page? `simple_html_dom` doesn't care where `$str` came from.

Comment: @Barmar please see the edit I've just made. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Your error logging is off... you are using `$ch` instead of `$curl`, and also after the resource has been closed. Try something like this: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/remote-content-shortcode/trunk/remote-content-shortcode.php#L114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your code, specifically around error handling. You are using the incorrect handle variable, `$ch`, when the rest of your code uses `$curl`. You should also fetch the error before closing the resource.

You will also need to decompress the response from the server as it is being sent via GZIP, which is why you see the strange characters. Use the [`CURLOPT_ENCODING`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) parameter with a value of "gzip" to do this. You can also use an empty string `""` to specify all compressions - this should probably be the default, but...

Check out the following code as an example:

```
// url to request
$base = 'https://kat.cr/applications/?rss=1';
// set up curl
$curl = curl_init();                                
// the url to request
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base );           
// return to variable
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
// decompress using GZIP
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
// don't verify peer ssl cert
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
//  // fetch remote contents, check for errors
if ( false === ( $response = curl_exec( $curl ) ) )
    $error = curl_error( $curl );
// close the resource
curl_close( $curl );

if ( !$response ){
    die("Curl Error: {$error}");
}

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load( $response );
// ... your code
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Unfortunatelly, even after altering the code, I have no error. Although, as mentioned, the print_r gives me strange characters

Comment: @Tayax Sorry I submitted it before I wrote the second part - it's GZIP compressed, so you have to specify the encoding to decompress it.

Comment: it's probably on the right way because i'm having a nice "Internal Server Error" when I run it now. Obviosuly the CURLOPT_ENCODING is doing somehting that my server doesn't like.

Comment: @Tayax It works for me when I use the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` line.

Comment: @barmar I have an Internal 500, and the log just shows "Premature end of script headers: index.php" . So i'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, the response that you are receivig from the request is encoded in base-64.

To solve this issue, you have to decode the string, using the folowing php function:

```
$html = base64_decode($html);
```

Where $html is the cUrl response.